# Lubuntu VM broken - X does not start and tty's do not allow commands

Tags: lubuntu, tty, virtualization

I'm running Lubuntu 12.04 in a VM under VMWare on Windows 7. After the last reboot, my X does not start, and any attempts to log in to tty's result in no command prompt being opened.

Is there anyway I can get a tty running to start troubleshooting? I'm quite stumped here as I cant really interact with the operating system at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since someone decided to vote this question up, I can answer what the problem was:

I had recently installed xmonad and messed with its config, rendering certain keybindings unusable (which I interpreted as X being broken). The problem with tty's malfunctioning still stands, however.